# QEventLoop usage(signals and slots)

Tags: qt, qt-signals, qeventloop

I have an application which contains such lines.

```
emit WindowAdded(settings->WindowType);//!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
MyWindow *widget = new MyWindow(0,settings,currentWindowIndex);
```

The signal changes value of `currentWindowIndex`, but it didn't work because of slot, it doesn't change its value in time. Some one advices me to use `QEventLoop`, but i don't understand how to do this. Give me an example, please. 
Another part of the code:

```
 connect(area,SIGNAL(WindowAdded(QString)),this,SLOT(addWindowOnTab(QString)));


void WorkSpace::addWindowOnTab(QString title)
{
    qint32 i = TabsList->addTab(title);/////!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
    emit addedWindowIndex(i);
    TabsList->setVisible(true);
}

connect(this,SIGNAL(addedWindowIndex(qint32)),area,SLOT(WindowIndexChanged(qint32)));

void MyMdiArea::WindowIndexChanged(qint32 index)
{
    currentWindowIndex=index;
}
```

I think it can help.

`MyMdArea` is сlass inherited from `QMdiArea`, `WorkSpace` is a `QWidget`, `TabsList` is a `QTabBar`.
And there is another fact: I tried to understand execution sequence of slots and added some lines to code:

```
QLabel *n= new QLabel("1");
n->show();
```

after emiting `WindowAdded` signal

```
QLabel *n= new QLabel("2");
n->show();
```

after emiting `addedWindowIndex` signal

and

```
QLabel *n= new QLabel("3");
n->show();
```

after changing `currentWindowIndex`'s value

and that is what i saw "1 2 3" and its exploded my brain. Maybe i don't understand something?

Comment: A signal does not change a value. As for the slot, you have not showed the connect statement, nor the slot definition, etc. It is not possible currently to give an accurate answer.

Comment: It's a little bit complicated becouse of signal connected with slot, that emit signal, that change this value, if you need it a can post all parts of code, but few huors later.

Comment: We need a simple code reproducing the issue: sscce.org. Currently, there can be too many things going wrong based on your question. We do not know anything about WindowAdded, MyWindow, your slot, etc.

Comment: In case you don't explicitly use Qt::QueuedConnection or multithreading, the slots are executed synchronously where you emit WindowAdded().

Comment: if `MyWindow` is derived of `QWidget` then you have to have a `QApplication` instance running and the applicaiton instance has a event loop running for you ... so we need more code to make clear what is going on here

Comment: user3081564, do not forget to paste more code. :)

Comment: Sorry to trouble. I solve this problem. The problem was in the wrong algorithm. So I wrote new algorithm and now it works))